# Send email up on reCAPTCHA verification

Tags: php, recaptcha

I'm trying to send an email of my sites form via php after the reCAPTCHA has been verified. The page refreshes up on clicking the submit button, but the email isn't sent. I think I'm missing something simple, but the things I've tried aren't working.

This is all done on localhost and the email sends fine with no reCAPTCHA code. Apologies for the explanation, I'm still new to all this.

HTML snippet:

```
<form class="contact100-form validate-form" action="#" method="post">
                            <span class="contact100-form-title">
                                Request a demo today!
                            </span>

                            <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input">
                                <input class="input100" type="text" required name="name" placeholder="Full Name">
                                <span class="focus-input100"></span>
                            </div>

                            <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input">
                                <input class="input100" type="text" required name="email" placeholder="E-mail">
                                <span class="focus-input100"></span>
                            </div>
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="MY KEY"></div>
</form>
```

PHP snippet:

```
<?php 
          /* [VERIFY CAPTCHA FIRST] */
            $secret = 'SECRET KEY'; // CHANGE THIS TO YOUR OWN!
            $url = "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=$secret&response=".$_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
            $verify = json_decode(file_get_contents($url));


          if($verify -> success)
          {
              $to = "email@email.com"; // this is your Email address
              $subject = "SUBJECT NAME";
              $email = $_POST['email];
              $name = $_POST['name'];


              $message = $name .  " wrote the following:" . "\n\n" . $_POST['message'] ."\n\n" . "Contact details: " . $from . "\n\n" . "Company Name: " . $company . "\n\n" . "Company Industry: " . $industry . "\n\n" . "Company Size: " . $size . "\n\n" . "Phone: " . $phone . "\n\n" . "Location: " . $location;

              $headers = "From:" . $from;
              $headers2 = "From:" . $to;
              mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
              mail($from,$headers2); // sends a copy of the message to the sender
              // echo "Mail Sent. Thank you " . $name . ", we will contact you shortly.";
              // You can also use header('Location: thank_you.php'); to redirect to another page.

          }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You miss a quote at `$email = $_POST['email];`

It should be `$email = $_POST['email'];`